# Get the image as Thumbnail

Tags: android, image, thumbnails

I am working in Android application but I'm stuck with the problem, when I get the image from camera I am displaying that image in imageview but I need to show the same image as thumbnail also. I have checked one application here is the [link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?ID=com.appspot.swisscodemonkeys.effectsfree&hl=en)

Here is the image:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following method to get thumbnails.

This method is useful when you have "Path" of image.

```
/**
 * Create a thumb of given argument size
 * 
 * @param selectedImagePath
 *            : String value indicate path of Image
 * @param thumbWidth
 *            : Required width of Thumb
 * @param thumbHeight
 *            : required height of Thumb
 * @return Bitmap : Resultant bitmap
 */
public static Bitmap createThumb(String selectedImagePath, int thumbWidth,
        int thumbHeight) {
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

    // Decode weakReferenceBitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath, options);

    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;

    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > thumbHeight || width > thumbWidth) {
        if (width > height) {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float) height / (float) thumbHeight);
        } else {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float) width / (float) thumbWidth);
        }
    }

    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    options.inSampleSize = inSampleSize;

    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath, options);
}
```

To use this method,

```
createThumb("path of image",100,100);
```

**Edit**

This method is used when you have **Bitmap** of your image.

```
public static Bitmap createThumb(Bitmap sourceBitmap, int thumbWidth,int thumbHeight) {
    return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(sourceBitmap, thumbWidth, thumbHeight,true);
}
```

to use this method

```
createThumb(editedImage, 100, 100);
```

Comment: Yes.. why not.. there is one another method for that. Wait.. editing my answer.

Comment: @priya, :) First you need to create a thumb, then you need to apply an effect on recently created thumb. Like, 1) Create a thumb of selected image, 2) apply effect, 3) set in gallery. Very simple.. :D

Comment: @priya, You can also see my application on play store by using keywork "i2cam" :)

Comment: @priya, not same time... You should create a background thread for that. to start image editing, http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/filters/index.html is a good start.

Comment: Simple.. download http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/filters/Filters.zip and you will accept my answer by opening this https://github.com/ajmas/JH-Labs-Java-Image-Filters link which provide you demo.. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this method will crate thumbnail of size you want will also maintain aspect ratio and scaling**

```
public Bitmap crateThumbNail(String imagePath,int size) {
        try {
            // Decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, o);
            // The new size we want to scale to
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE = size;

            // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            int scale = 1;
            while (o.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE && o.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE)
                scale *= 2;

            // Decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, o2);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }
```