# creating .bmp image file from Bitmap class

Tags: java, android, bitmap, png, bmp

I've created an application that uses sockets in which the client receives the image and stores the data of the image in Bitmap class....

Can anyone please tell me how to create a file named **myimage.png** or **myimage.bmp** from this Bitmap object

```
String base64Code = dataInputStream.readUTF();
byte[] decodedString = null;
decodedString = Base64.decode(base64Code);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0,decodedString.length);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try following code to save image as **PNG** format

```
try {
   FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filename);
   bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
} catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
out.flush();
out.close();
```

Here, 100 is quality to save in Compression. You can pass anything between 0 to 100. Lower the digit, poor quality with decreased size.

**Note**

You need to take permission in Android Manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

**Edit**

To save your image to **.BMP** format, **[Android Bitmap Util](https://github.com/ultrakain/AndroidBitmapUtil/blob/master/src/com/ultrasonic/android/image/bitmap/util/AndroidBmpUtil.java)** will help you. It has very simple implementation.

```
String sdcardBmpPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/sample_text.bmp";
Bitmap testBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.sample_text);
AndroidBmpUtil bmpUtil = new AndroidBmpUtil();
boolean isSaveResult = bmpUtil.save(testBitmap, sdcardBmpPath);
```

Comment: when i tried this -------------FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("Image.png");
      bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);-----------------------i'm getting --------------java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Image.png: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)

Comment: @user2318483, you can use like following. String fileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "your_file.png";

Comment: sir when i send large image files such as 50KB 400X400 i'm getting java.nio.BufferOverflowException

Comment: @user2318483, are you doing your testing in Emulator?

Comment: @user2318483, i tried with 1600 * 1200 resolution with size 1.3 MB image. I tested in Actual device and not getting such exception. I think it is due to low memory of emulator if you are running in it.. :)

Comment: sir i'm not running the android in emulator.....but runs in android tablet connected on my PC

Comment: @user2318483, okay then try `BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(out);` and `bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos);` code.

Comment: sir here's the  place where i'm getting java.nio.BufferOverflowException--------------------------- boolean isSaveResult = bmpUtil.save(bitmap, sdcardBmpPath);

Comment: @user2318483, oh dear.. bmpUtil.. i didn't implemented it with large sized. Code is not developed by me my friend. Sorry. In this case I can't help you.. :(

Comment: sir where should i paste this code.........................BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(out); and bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos);

Comment: it was for my code my friend. The link which i provided is a library developed by other person. I didn't examine it. :(

Comment: the problem is with the size sir......when i tried for small size it work perfectly

Comment: I examine the code.. there is array `int[] pixels = new int[width * height];` which consume memory and other one is file operation. Is it possible to reduce size of your bitmap? Then try my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18570687/get-the-image-as-thumnail/18570836#18570836

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
   FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filename);
   bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
} catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
   out.close();
}
```